# In Azure durable functions ,How can I get the output of one activity function as an input for another function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am statrting new with Azure Durable functions, and I followed the tutorials and was able to run it without any error. As I see, my requirement will be to take output from one of the activity function and use as an input to other activity function, also the other activity function shouldnt start, unless the previous activity function has been completed. How can I do this?

Here is the code which runs: I would like "Hello" activity function return value which is src_client should be used as an input to activity function "Goodbye"

```
import logging
import json

import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df


def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    result1 = yield context.call_activity('Hello', "bestday-demo")
    result2 = yield context.call_activity('Goodbye', "Seattle")
    result3 = yield context.call_activity('Hello', "London")
    return [result1, result2, result3]

main = df.Orchestrator.create(orchestrator_function)
```

and this is my activity function "Hello"

```
import logging
from myownsdk import myClient


def main(projectname: str) -> str:
    SRC_PROJECT_DAY = projectname
    src_client = myClient(
        api_key= "Myapikey",
        client_name= "Proj-DEMO_CLIENT",
        project = SRC_PROJECT_DAY,
        debug=False
        )
    return f"{src_client}"
```

and this is my activity function "Goodbye". This returns "Goodbye Seattle", but I would like to pass my src_client from Hello activity function and use that to get some more results.

```
import logging
from myownsdk import myClient


def main(name: str) -> str:    
    return f"GoodBye {name}!"
```

Also how can i make sure, Goodbye runs only when Hello has been exceuted and completed. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are calling goodbye function and the string Seattle in result2 and there is no way the orchestration is happening.

[image]

I observe that your orchestrator function isn't same when compared to [original document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=python#chaining) So please make sure that you are calling it in a right way , As per the below code try to make changes in your code.

```
 import azure.functions as func
    import azure.durable_functions as df
      
   def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
        result1 = yield context.call_activity('Hello', "bestday-demo")
        result2 = yield context.call_activity('Goodbye', result1)
        result3 = yield context.call_activity('Hello', result2)
        return result3
    
    
    main = df.Orchestrator.create(orchestrator_function)
```

Also, try to make changes in your Good Bye Activity Function.

```
import logging
from myownsdk import myClient


def main(name: str) -> str:    
    return f"GoodBye seattle {name}!"
```

Comment: yes I figured that out and thank you for pointing this. one more question here: DO you know what is the time out limit for orchestrator function. suppose if I have a transformation which is happening between 3 different activity function and it takes more than 30 mins for transformation to complete, will my Orchestrator function time out? or is there any configuration I can do to let my orchestrator function stay alive until all transformation completes

Comment: Could you please help me with your Function App Service Plan

Comment: Where do i see my plan? lets say I have the most basic consumption one

Comment: > Where do i see my plan?

You can view your plan type in your function app overview page and you need to select your plan type while creating function app as per the below image
[Function App Resource Plan Type](https://imgur.com/pLogLhi)

Comment: > lets say I have the most basic consumption one

As per this [Function Time Out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) Document. The time out limit for consumption plan will be 5 minutes by default but if we use the below code we can extend the time out limit upto 60 minutes as per this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/328952/azure-durable-functions-timeout-error-in-activity.html). 

    {
        "functionTimeout": "00:30:00"
    }

Comment: and that goes for orchestrator function as well.. what I heard is Orchestrator function is meant for long running tasks..but if thats the case, i.e.5 mins, then there is no point having multiple activity function

Comment: My second comment shows you the code to increase your time out limit

Comment: i know I am asking a lot here and is off the topic originally posted, but that means If I define the time limit and make it unbounded, its include all the activity function called from orchestrator function? and we dont have to define it for each activity function

Comment: > orchestrator creating 250 activity calls, with `functionTimeout` set
> as `"01:00:00"`
 
 As per the above statement from the Orchestrator timeout document which I sent earlier there is no need to define time out property for each activity function.

Comment: If my Answer is helpful could you please accept my answer to help the other community members and could you please open new request so that the off topic answer may help other community members

Comment: Hi @SaiSakethGuduru-MT do you mind sharing your knowledge to help me resolve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72266862/logger-becomes-null-in-azure-durable-function/72274240 ? I'm also trying to call a function and use its returned value in the following code where the value would be passed to another function. Yet the returned value doesn't seem right once it's passed back to the orchestrator.